# Scala: missing arguments for method count in trait

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In one line of code I'm attempting to take the first 10 lines of an RDD and count the records (which obviously should be 10).  However, when I do some I get the error:

```
<console>:24: error: missing arguments for method count in trait 
TraversableOnce;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Here is the code:

```
logfiles.filter(line => line.contains("jpg")).take(10).count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you `take(10)`, you're no longer dealing with an `RDD`, but a `Traversable` (Scala collection type). You want to use `size` instead of `count`, since `count` takes a predicate to filter by:

```
val count = logfiles.filter(line => line.contains("jpg")).take(10).size
```

As you've stated, this will trivially always return 10 items as long as your `RDD` has at least that many items, and you most likely want to use `RDD.count()` instead.

```
val count = logfiles.filter(line => line.contains("jpg")).count()
```

Comment: "this will trivially always return 10" Not always. However, the reasonable simplification would be `Math.min(...count(), 10)`.

Comment: @Alexey Of course, given the `RDD` has at least 10 items.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the documentation of RDD

```
def take(num: Int): Array[T]
```

Returns Array not an RDD hence the count function doesn't work.

Also in RDD there is no native way of selecting 10 elements. If you really want to do that you should probably convert the RDD to a dataframe and use limit function in dataframe

```
  df.limit(10) will return a dataframe of 10 elements
```

Where you can perform the count operation